# Efficient way of finding the roots of a polynomial equation expressed as Rayleigh quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector and $\mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive definite covariance matrix. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be an *unknown* scalar. Then, what is the most efficient way to solve the following equation:

\begin{align}
(1-a) \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{Q}^{-1} (\mathbf{I} - a \mathbf{Q})^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{u} =  \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{u}.
\end{align}

The resulting equation will be a polynomial in $a$. By just taking a look at the equation, we observe that $a=0$ is a trivial solution. What about other roots?

Perhaps, starting with $n=3$ would be a good idea, which gives a third order polynomial. But can we find a closed-form expression of the roots of the above equation?

Comment: If $\mathbf Q$ is invertible, it’s positive *definite*, right? Do you have any assumptions about $\mathbf Q$ and/or $a$ guaranteeing the invertibility of $\mathbf I - a \mathbf Q$?

Comment: Changed $\mathbf{Q}$ to positive definite. Yes, it is invertible. $\mathbf{Q}$ is symmetric and positive definite. These are the only assumptions.

Comment: As $\mathbf I - a\mathbf Q$ commutes with $\mathbf Q$, its inverse commutes with it as well, so you may cancel the outer conjugation.

Comment: Right, that gives us $(1-a) \mathbf{u}^T (\mathbf{I} - a\mathbf{Q})^{-1} \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: Let $\mathbf A = \mathbf I - a \mathbf Q$. If $\mathbf Q$ is symmetric, so is $\mathbf A$. By the spectral theorem, there is an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf U$ with $\mathbf D_a = \mathbf U^{-1} \mathbf A \mathbf U$ being diagonal. Letting $\mathbf u' = \mathbf U^{-1} \mathbf u$, the equation to solve now becomes
$$(1-a)\mathbf u'^T \mathbf D_a^{-1} \mathbf u' = \mathbf u'^T \mathbf u.$$
The entries of $D_a$ must be polynomial in $a$. Maybe this eases your problem. That’s all I got. Good luck, I’m going to bed now.

Comment: What are we solving for here? $\mathbf{u}$?

Comment: k.stm's answer provides an answer (or most of one) to your question about finding a closed form expression. There is no nice closed form expression giving the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix. So it almost certainly the case that no closed form will be available here either. One thing to note is that $u$ is an unknown in $n$ variables, but you have a single 1-dimensional equation here. Therefore the solution set for $u$ should be of dimension $n-1$.